# Server is not able to authenticate user if i send NSHTTPCookie iOS9

Tags: python, swift, server, ios9

This may be the basic question but i am unable to investigate the issue. Need your help if anyone experience it.

During creation of NSURLRequest, i am setting handle cookies property to true.

```
urlRequest.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=true
```

When login response comes, we are saving cookies; Please have a look at code:

```
//Stored the cookies in shared place
let allHeaderFileds = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as! [String : String]
let cookies: NSArray? = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(allHeaderFileds, forURL: (response?.URL)!)
if let _ = cookies
{
    NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookies(cookies! as! [NSHTTPCookie], forURL: (response?.URL)!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
}
```

When we are making another API call in which we need those cookies, we are also setting it here like following:

```
let cookieProperties:NSDictionary = [
    NSHTTPCookieName:cookie.name!,
    NSHTTPCookieValue:cookie.value!,
    NSHTTPCookieDomain:cookie.domain!,
    NSHTTPCookiePath:cookie.path!
]
let cookie:NSHTTPCookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties as! [String : AnyObject])!
NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(cookie)
```

When i hit an API call to get data, it returns status code 403 and Message “Authentication credentials were not provided.”

For more details about header, please look into this:

```
"<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fb5227444a0> { URL: http://172.16.10.249:8001/api/v1/users/profile/ } { status code: 403, headers {\n    Allow = \"GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS\";\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"application/json\";\n    Date = \"Thu, 28 Jan 2016 10:22:22 GMT\";\n    Server = \"WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11\";\n    Vary = \"Accept, Cookie\";\n    \"X-Frame-Options\" = SAMEORIGIN;\n} }"
```

Please let me know if i am wrong at any point or we need some extra configuration on iOS9. If server need to do some more steps please also mention it. Our server is written in Python.